# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied and Subprocess error

Tags: python, subprocess

```
    PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-bab992cc7bb5> in <module>()
     67 
     68 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 69     main()

/content/gdrive/My Drive/LORE/pyyadt.py in fit(df, class_name, columns, features_type, discrete, continuous, filename, path, sep, log)
     32     cmd = 'yadt/dTcmd -fd %s -fm %s -sep %s -d %s' % (
     33         data_filename, names_filename, sep, tree_filename)
---> 34     output = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
     35     # cmd = r"dTcmd -fd %s -fm %s -sep '%s' -d %s" % (
     36     #     data_filename, names_filename, sep, tree_filename)

/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    354 
    355     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 356                **kwargs).stdout
    357 
    358 

/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    421         kwargs['stdin'] = PIPE
    422 
--> 423     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    424         try:
    425             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    727                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    728                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 729                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    730         except:
    731             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1362                         if errno_num == errno.ENOENT:
   1363                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
-> 1364                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1365                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1366 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'yadt/dTcmd'
```

I am unable to access the file and hence script not running. Tried different python versions as well in virtual envs. Any help on this subprocess error?

The file 'dTcmd' have no extension.

Comment: does the dTcmd have +x bit ?  Is it a script with shebang - and possible that shebang pointing to some interpreter that the use running the python script does not have access to ?

Comment: I am not sure but i don't think its an executable file. I am trying to run this repo to check results (https://github.com/riccotti/LORE) by runinng the file test_lore.py If you can please let me know if its running for you? @rasjani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to execute the file named `yadt/dTcmd`, but it's not marked executable. Add the execute permission (for all users) like this:

```
chmod a+x yadt/dTcmd
```

Comment: I think the file is not executable explicitly, I think it stores some data while line 32 is trying to fetch. I am trying this repo to check results (https://github.com/riccotti/LORE) by running the script test_lore.py If you can please check if its running for you?

Comment: No, line 32 is definetely trying to execute it. It's an ELF executable file in the repo you linked to. Normally Git (on Linux) will properly preserve executable bits, but if you downloaded the repo as a ZIP file you sometimes need to add them back yourself.

Comment: Got it, I earlier downloaded the zip on mac. Running via Git on ubuntu worked! Thanks a ton.